# i want to handle a string by regex, but how to write the right regex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

i have four strings, which are "a.mob", "b.mob", "c.mob", "d.mob", "e.mob"

i want to match "a.mob", "b.mob", "d.mob" and any string end with ".mob" but except "c.mob" and "e.mob", i try to write a regex match:

```
"^(?!.*(c|e)).*?(?!mob)"
```

it done the work, but i think it hard to read and get.

in my mind, there maybe some simple match which is clear and simple.

my question is, is my match too complicate? is regex the best solution here?

Comment: You have five strings, not four! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to SO.

If you want to "match a string ending with *something*", you have to use `$` in your regex (and don't forget to quote the `.`, it's a special character in regexen):

```
"^[^ce]\\.mob$"
```

(otherwise you'll match `biloximob5`, for instance).

If your strings may be different than the five you have shown, maybe you'll have to be more generic:

```
"^([^ce]|..+)?\\.mob$"
```

for instance, matches `.mob`, `elefante.mob`, but does not match `.mobi` or `e.mob`...

May I suggest a regex-trying tool like [regexr](http://regexr.com/)? It might be a good idea so you can train in the use of regexen.

Update: don't forget to quote the backslashes when you go back from perl/regexr to c++....

Comment: thank you first.but i if i don't want to match "not.mob", "^[^not]\.mob$" doesn't work:(

Comment: @Isaturn, in regex sometimes it's easier if you start with what you **do want** to match, and let the things you don't want to match for the end, or for another regex, which you will test for non-matching; like: `regex ends_with_mob("\\.mob$"), starts_with_c_e_or_not("^(c|e|not)\\.mob$"); if( match(ends_with_mob, str) && !match(starts_with_c_e_or_not, str) ) { /* do your thing here */ }`